# Unresolvable circular reference with @RefreshScope on @Configuration or @SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to get the refreshed value of my property `apiKey`, after modifying it and requesting the `/refresh` endpoint.

For some reason my bean is unable to get the refreshed value even when annotated with `@RefreshScope`. I added `@RefreshScope` on my class as I did for my `DatasourceConfig` but in this case I'm getting this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.application': Initialization of bean failed;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.application.initTimestamp.transformer.handler': Invocation of init method failed;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.application': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  scopedTarget.application
└─────┘
```

Here is my `Application.java` :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableSwagger2
@RefreshScope
public class Application{

    @Value("${api.key}")
    private String apiKey;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private IMonitoringsService monitoringsService;

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel initTimestampChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @RefreshScope
    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "initTimestampChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "${start.task.rate}"))
    public MessageSource<?> buildRequestMessageSource() {
        MethodInvokingMessageSource source = new MethodInvokingMessageSource();
        source.setObject(tasksService);
        source.setMethodName("requestAllTasks");
        System.out.println(apiKey);
        return source;
    }

}
```

Yet it's working for my `DatasourceConfig` :

```
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfig {
    @Value("${spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active}")
    private int maxActive;

    @RefreshScope
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) dataSource;
        ds.setMaxActive(maxActive);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

I'm using :

```
<spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
<spring-boot-version>1.5.9.RELEASE</spring-boot-version>
```

Comment: You shouldn't put `@RefreshScope` on `@Configuration` classes. What versions are you using of boot and cloud?

Comment: I've updated my post. Does it mean that the only solution is to use `@ConfigurationProperties` ?

Comment: No, you could also pass a Spring  `Environment` into `dataSource()`.

Answer (score 0):

As spencergibb suggested, you shouldn't put `@SpringBootApplication` and `@RefreshScope` on the same class. Remove `@RefreshScope` from `Application` and move the configuration that needs `@RefreshScope` to a separate class.